# Why does the character sequence //(* change the font of the rest of my source file in codeblocks 12.11?

Tags: c++, c, syntax-highlighting, codeblocks

If I add `//(*` to an un-commented line in my source code, the rest of the font becomes italicized and changes color. The code still seems to compile however. And I cannot find a way to "undo" this change of font sequence with some other sequence. What is this used for? This occurs in C and C++ code so far as I can tell, and it does not occur in vim. Im using Windows 7 and CodeBlocks 12.11.

Comment: Looks like an extension to allow `*/` in multiline comments. You can end it with `//*)`.

Comment: It turns out that sequence does not end it for me, unfortunately. -- nevermind, it will end it if it occurs on a different line. Thanks chris!

Comment: Well, I don't see anything on it anywhere, so I guess I'll make that an answer unless someone else knows anything about it. I've never seen it before. And it's not even like I thought. The code in there is still compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//(*` and `//*)` is a special comment block used to identify code that is automatically generated by the wxSmith plugin included with Code::Blocks.

Comment: Are you sure? I could have sworn I changed that to bright green and nothing happened. EDIT: Never mind, I somehow got the inactive one, but missed this. Nice one.

Comment: @chris I dug into the source code ;) - it's in `src\sdk\wxscintilla\src\scintilla\lexers\LexCPP.cxx` around line 853.

Comment: Heh heh. I can't believe I went through the syntax highlighting customization and missed that :p

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be an IDE extension, but for what, I have no clue at all. All I can say is that you can end it by putting `//*)` on a new line:

[image: colours example]

One might think this could be used to have multiline comments that contain `*/`. However, the catch is that the darkened code still compiles. Why it would be a different colour and not act different is beyond me.